# Ayuda redimensionar imagen y marca de agua

Tags: php, imagen, upload

Tengo este script y quisiera agregarle una marca de agua al subirla al servidor  pero no se como hacerlo me podrían ayudar

```html
 <?php if ((isset($_POST["enviado"])) && ($_POST["enviado"] == "form1")) {

if(isset($_FILES['userfile']))
  
  if(($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]) != "")  
{  
  function fun_resizejpg($imgsrc,$imgnew,$newx,$newy,$quality){  
        if( file_exists($imgsrc) )     {  
        list($srcx,$srcy,$ext) = getimagesize($imgsrc);       
        switch( $ext)       {    
        case 1 :     
        $old = imagecreatefromgif($imgsrc);                     
        $img = imagecreate($srcx,$srcy);
        imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);                             
        imagecopy($img,$old,0,0,0,0,$srcx,$srcy); 
        break;               
        case 2 :     
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgsrc); 
        break;                           
        case 3 :     
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($imgsrc);
         break;    
        case 6:     
        $img = imagecreatefromwbmp($imgsrc);  
        break;               
        default:
        print_r(getimagesize($imgsrc)); 
        return false;       }                
        $tamx=$srcx;         
        $tamy=$srcy;        
        if($srcx>$newx)
        $pv=($srcx>$srcy)?$srcx/$newx:$srcy/$newy;        
        elseif($srcy>$newy)
        $pv=($srcy>$srcx)?$srcy/$newy:$srcx/$newx;        
        if(isset($pv)){    
        $srcx=ceil($srcx/$pv);     
        $srcy=ceil($srcy/$pv);     }               
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor ($srcx, $srcy);             
        imagecopyresampled ($new, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $srcx, $srcy, $tamx, $tamy);                     
        imagejpeg($new,(substr($imgnew,0,strrpos($imgnew,"."))).".jpg",$quality);        
        imagedestroy($img);              
        return true;    
        } 
        else 
        return false;
        
  }
  
   
   
$nombre_nuevo = time().'.jpg';
$carpeta = '../../imagenes/noticias/';


  if($_FILES['userfile']['error']==0)
  
  {  if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile']['name']))
    { fun_resizejpg($_FILES['userfile']['name'],$carpeta.$nombre_nuevo,600,600,50);
     $ok_image = true;
    }
    
    else echo 'Ocurrio un error al subir la imagen';
  }
  else echo 'Ocurrio un error al subir la imagen';

if (file_exists($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {

$borrar = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

 unlink($borrar);

} 

} 
 ?>
```

Comment: Cuál es exactamente tu duda? en qué parte te has quedado atascado? Deberías leer el apartado de cómo preguntar, aquí te dejo el enlace:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask